# How to get HTTP error stream using Python requests library?

Tags: python, python-requests

How do I access the error stream using the Python `requests` library? For example, using `HttpURLConnection` in Java, I would do something like:

```
InputStream errorStream = conn.getErrorStream();
```

Is there a function like this with `requests`?
I'm looking for the error message in the response that was supplied by the source, NOT the error status e.g. Internal Server Error

Comment: You mean the body content of the response?

Comment: Well, in Java calling `getInputStream`, which gets the response content, would throw an exception if the response code was an error response. In that situation you'd have to call `getErrorStream`. Are you saying that `requests` treats them both the same? So calling `response.text` will give me whatever is available?

Comment: Well, give it a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`requests` won't raise an exception if HTTP error occurs, but you can get the error message in the response content. Example:

```
url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/does_not_exist'
r = requests.get(url)
print(r.status_code, r.reason)
print(r.text)
```

Comment: I'd misunderstood HTTP responses in general. I thought error responses were set in a separate part of the raw response, but presumably the Java example I posted forces you to call `getErrorStream` to make sure you know you're retrieving an error response, to prevent accidentally calling `getInputStream` thinking your response is good.

Comment: You can raise `HTTPError` exceptions if you want with [`raise_for_status()`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/#response-status-codes)